# Import a json file in Pandas with ISODate date column

Tags: json, pandas

I have a large json file that contains some text and other information.
The problem is that it also contains a date field that looks like:

`ISODate("2015-05-04T01:34:29Z")`

I would like to read this json file in Pandas and make the appropriate conversion into a "real" date field.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the convert_dates parameter when reading json with the [read_json](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) function.

Basically use it like this:

```
pd.read_json('my.json', convert_dates=['column_with_funky_date'])
```

This may not work for this date format and in that case I am afraid you are a bit out of luck.

Comment: You could do some hacky stuff to get this to work if you are using a unix system. Like: cat filename | sed 's/ISODate("//g' | sed 's/")//g' > newfile This will strip the ISODate("") but keep what is inside it. Maybe after that you could load the data. Not very clean, but may work for you.

Comment: @Noobie & firelynx:  It doesn't look like `read_json` has an option `date_parser` like `read_csv` does.  But you should be able to load normally and then use the `format` option of `to_datetime` in order to precisely specify the datetime format.